# setting Windows Service start from settings file c#

Tags: c#, windows-services, settings, scheduled-tasks

I have a windows service that I want to be able to run at a time specified in my settings file.

[image]

This is my first time trying to use a Windows service. how can I schedule a job based on this value in the settings file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used a different method to deal with this probelm - 
I have the service running all the time, and the service uses timers to act when I want it to act. 
the timer can be control via a file or whatever other method you choose.

You can use windows scheduler to start the service at a specific time, just use it... put the service start command in a batch file and run it at a specific time.

[Shchdule a task](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-sg/windows7/schedule-a-task)

Answer (score 0):

you can't.  You can however have a setup task which creates scheduled tasks to start and stop the service.